# Using custom collections in p:datatable

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use a custom collection for my p:datatable

Custom Collection:

```
public class ManagedArrayList<E> extends java.util.ArrayList<E> {

private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE_LIMIT = 0; //unlimited
private ArrayList<E> internalList;
private int maxSize;

public ManagedArrayList(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    internalList = new ArrayList<E> ();
}

public ManagedArrayList() {
    this(DEFAULT_SIZE_LIMIT);
}

@Override
public boolean add(E objectToAdd){
    if(maxSize>0){
        if(internalList.size()>maxSize){
            throw new IllegalStateException("List is full");
        }
    }
    return internalList.add(objectToAdd);
}

@Override
public E get(int index){
    return internalList.get(index);
}

@Override
public E remove(int index){
    return internalList.remove(index);
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object o){
    return internalList.remove(o);
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return internalList.iterator();
}

public List<E> toList(){
    return (List)internalList;
}
}
```

However when I use this as is i get the message: "No records found."
If I convert my custom list to `<List>` first it works fine. 
Converting my list:

```
private ManagedArrayList<FragmentTuple> fragments = new ManagedArrayList();

public List<FragmentTuple> getUICompatibleFragments() {
    List<FragmentTuple> f = this.fragments.toList();
    return f;
}
```

I would prefere to use my custom collection directly without having to convert. Is there something i am missing in my implementation of ManagedArrayList so that it will work in p:datatable and preferably also in ui:repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to override among others the [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--) and [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty--) methods. Moreover, you're never delegating to `ArrayList` superclass, but keeping an internal `ArrayList` instance. One would wonder why you extend from `ArrayList` at all instead of [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) or even [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which would in turn automatically force you to implement the right methods. An alternative would thus be to delegate to the `ArrayList` superclass instead of having an internal instance, so that the `size()` and `isEmpty()` calls would "automagically" return the right values.

Comment: Hi thanks for the hints.
How would I delegate to the superclass?

Comment: I ended up adding

    public int size() {
        return internalList.size();
    }
    

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return internalList.isEmpty();
    }

and extending AbstractList instead of ArrayList. Everything works fine now thanks.

Comment: As to delegating to super, just replace `internalList.xxx()` by `super.xxx()` and get rid of the whole field.